# Retrieving Array from Parse

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, ios8

I created an array that contains different numbers and each time the button is clicked the array advances to the next index number.

```
var currentNumber = 0 

var random = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

@IBAction func numberUp(sender: UIButton) 

numberLabel.text = random[currentNumber]

++currentNumber
```

I tried to get similar results in with Parse but i couldn't. I created a class with a array in it

```
var numbers = PFObject(className:"Numbers")

numbers["number"] = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]

numbers.save()
```

How would i go about doing the same thing but with the array i created on Parse. Or how could i retrieve the array from Parse and assign it to a local array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create a PFQuery like

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Numbers")
```

Create a query to download the data in the table:

```
let result = query.find()
```

Then assume you have only one row in the table:

```
let arrayOfNumbers = result.first
```

Then you can iterate on arrayOfNumbers